# How to remove white edges from Sign In With Apple button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**Problem** - The official ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton from Apple shows white edges. I would like these to be removed.

**What I've tried** - Margin=0, Padding=0, and tried to set CornerRadius, but had none worked for me.

**Implementation** - I've implemented the Sign in with Apple functionality in my iOS app, using the following as a guide https://github.com/Redth/Xamarin.AppleSignIn.Sample/tree/master/XamarinFormsAppleSignIn

There's a custom button in the shared project files, and a renderer that uses Apple's official ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton in the iOS project. This ensures that it follows the button design from Apple.

I'm aware that buttons are rectangular, but would like to remove the white edges. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT MADE:**

**XAML:**

```
<controls:AppleSignInButton SignIn="OnAppleLoginClicked" ButtonStyle="Black" Visual="None" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" IsVisible="{Binding IsAppleSignInAvailable}"/>
```

**C# - Apple button class in Shared project:**

```
public class AppleSignInButton : Button
    {
        public AppleSignInButtonStyle ButtonStyle { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler SignIn;

        public AppleSignInButton()
        {
            Clicked += OnAppleSignInButtonClicked;
            Text = "Sign in with Apple";
            BorderWidth = 1;

            SetAppleButtonStyle();

            switch (ButtonStyle)
            {
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.Black:
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                    TextColor = Color.White;
                    BorderColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.White:
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                    TextColor = Color.Black;
                    BorderColor = Color.White;
                    break;
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.WhiteOutline:
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                    TextColor = Color.Black;
                    BorderColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void OnAppleSignInButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SignIn?.Invoke(sender, e);
            Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }

        private void SetAppleButtonStyle()
        {
            // check if we are in light or dark mode
            if (Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Light)
            {
                // use Black Apple button
                ButtonStyle = AppleSignInButtonStyle.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                // use White Apple button
                ButtonStyle = AppleSignInButtonStyle.WhiteOutline;
            }
        }

        public void InvokeSignInEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
            => SignIn?.Invoke(sender, e);

        public void Dispose()
            => Clicked -= OnAppleSignInButtonClicked;
    }

    public enum AppleSignInButtonStyle
    {
        Black,
        White,
        WhiteOutline
    }
```

**Apple's SignIn button Renderer in iOS project:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyAppName.Controls.AppleSignInButton), typeof(MyAppName.iOS.Renderers.AppleSignInButtonRenderer))]

namespace MyAppName.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class AppleSignInButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<AppleSignInButton, UIView>
    {
        public static ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonType ButtonType { get; set; } = ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonType.Default;

        bool Is13 => UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0);

        ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton button;
        UIButton oldButton;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AppleSignInButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Cleanup
                if (Is13)
                {
                    if (button != null)
                        button.TouchUpInside -= Button_TouchUpInside;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (oldButton != null)
                        oldButton.TouchUpInside -= Button_TouchUpInside;
                }
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Create
                if (Is13)
                {
                    if (button == null)
                    {
                        button = (ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton)CreateNativeControl();
                        button.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;

                        SetNativeControl(button);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (oldButton == null)
                    {
                        oldButton = (UIButton)CreateNativeControl();
                        oldButton.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
                        oldButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
                        oldButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
                        oldButton.ClipsToBounds = true;
                        oldButton.SetTitle(" " + Element.Text, UIControlState.Normal);

                        switch (Element.ButtonStyle)
                        {
                            case AppleSignInButtonStyle.Black:
                                oldButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
                                oldButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
                                oldButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                                break;
                            case AppleSignInButtonStyle.White:
                                oldButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                                oldButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
                                oldButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
                                break;
                            case AppleSignInButtonStyle.WhiteOutline:
                                oldButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                                oldButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
                                oldButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                                break;
                        }

                        SetNativeControl(oldButton);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override UIView CreateNativeControl()
        {
            if (!Is13)
                return new UIButton(UIButtonType.Plain);
            else
                return new ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton(ButtonType, GetButtonStyle());
        }

        ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonStyle GetButtonStyle()
        {
            switch (Element.ButtonStyle)
            {
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.Black:
                    return ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonStyle.Black;
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.White:
                    return ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonStyle.White;
                case AppleSignInButtonStyle.WhiteOutline:
                    return ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonStyle.WhiteOutline;
            }

            return ASAuthorizationAppleIdButtonStyle.Black;
        }

        void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
            => Element.InvokeSignInEvent(sender, e);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show me your full code in Xaml? I can't reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: Set Button backgroundColor as parent background color

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT I have added more code that should help you replicate the issue. Prasanth has pointed me to the right direction, and the answer was to set BackgroundColor="Transparent". Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Prasanth many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @paddystar nice to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Prasanth for pointing me in the right direction.
I wanted the button to look rounded, but without the white edges.

To achieve this, simply set BackgroundColor="Transparent" for the button.
Or you can set it to match the View's background colour, but I prefer transparent.

[image]

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).